# Where can I learn to make Cardano NFTs that have varying rarity levels when they are purchased for the first time?

Tags: ada, native-assets, nft, gougen, learning

I have seen some really cool projects like cryptoknitties and crypties with rarity levels and they usually come in like 5-10k. I have some great ideas but I can't find anywhere to learn how to do this on the internet or Cardano website? Are there any resources available to learn how to do Cardano NFTs like that?

Comment: What are cnfts?

Comment: @gRebel I think they mean Cardano NFTs (cnfts). In which case we have several helpful question/answers within the [community](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/search?q=nft).

Comment: I will edit the question based on the assumption that you are correct.  I had assumed the same but was checking with the original poster.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can start looking at [this guide](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/getting-started-with-native-tokens.html). They covered all the details needed for mint your own tokens directly from the cli. Also if you want to create it in a mainstream programming language you can take a look at these libraries:

- [cardano-wallet-js](https://github.com/tango-crypto/cardano-wallet-js) (Javascript)
- [cardano-client-lib](https://github.com/bloxbean/cardano-client-lib) (Java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to create native tokens or NFTs: https://cardano-native-token.com
This is the easiest userfriendly way at the moment.
It's required to have more technical skills if you want to make more complicate NFT setup.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly built into Cardano that provides this functionality. You would personally control releases. If you want to mint a single item, do that. If you want to mint 100, do that. Of course as the amount rises, the less convenient it is to do this manually. I imagine anyone that's doing this with any level of seriousness is also writing a stack of custom tools to manage the process from creation through sales.

Eventually there will be marketplaces available that will do a lot of this for you; for a service fee, of course.